# mongo java driver 2.14.0. Change Deprecated code

Tags: java, spring, mongo-java-driver

I am upgrading mongo java driver jar to 2.14.0. my old code working fine but following code showing deprecated classes and constructor so I need compatible code without deprecated classes and constructor for mongo-java-driver.jar 2.14.0.

```
public MongoTemplate getMongoTemplate() {

    SimpleMongoDbFactory simpleMongoDbFactory = null;

    try {

        MongoOptions opts = new MongoOptions();//depricate

        opts.threadsAllowedToBlockForConnectionMultiplier = getThreadsAllowedToBlockForConnectionMultiplier();//depricate

        opts.connectionsPerHost = getConnectionsPerHost();//depricate

        ServerAddress addr = new ServerAddress(getHost(), getPort());

        Mongo mongo = new Mongo(addr, opts);//depricate

        simpleMongoDbFactory = new SimpleMongoDbFactory(mongo,
                getDatabaseName());//depricate

        if (mongoTemplate == null) {

            mongoTemplate = new MongoTemplate(simpleMongoDbFactory);

        }

    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {

        LOGGER.error(e.getMessage());

    } catch (MongoException e) {

        LOGGER.error(e.getMessage());

    }

    return mongoTemplate;
}
```

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: where I mentioned deprecated those lines want to replace with spring-data-mongodb-1.9.2.jar 's code.

Answer (score 1):

This is not Spring Data MongoDB code. This is code from the MongoDB Java driver that has beed deprecated quite a while ago already. Users are incentivized to use `MongoClient` over `Mongo`, `MongoClientOptions` over `MongoOptions` etc.

Comment: Thanks.. That was my mistake. you are right this code is of MongoDB Java driver which has been deprecated in new version of mongo java driver.

Answer (score 1):

Equivalent code for the same is

```
public MongoTemplate getMongoTemplate() {

    SimpleMongoDbFactory simpleMongoDbFactory = null;

    try {
        Builder builder =MongoClientOptions.builder();
        builder.threadsAllowedToBlockForConnectionMultiplier(getThreadsAllowedToBlockForConnectionMultiplier());
        builder.connectionsPerHost(getConnectionsPerHost());
        MongoClientOptions options = builder.build();

        ServerAddress addr = new ServerAddress(getHost(), getPort());
        MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient(addr, options);

        simpleMongoDbFactory = new SimpleMongoDbFactory(mongo,getDatabaseName());

        if (mongoTemplate == null) {

            mongoTemplate = new MongoTemplate(simpleMongoDbFactory);

        }

    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {

        LOGGER.error(e.getMessage());

    } catch (MongoException e) {

        LOGGER.error(e.getMessage());

    }

    return mongoTemplate;
}
```