# Connecting MongoDB atlas cluster with morphia

Tags: mongodb, kotlin, morphia, ktor

I have been trying to connect my kotlin + Ktor application to a mongodb atlas cluster using [morphia](https://morphia.dev/). I have followed several tutorials on how to do it but every time I am getting this error:

```
    at com.example.ApplicationKt.main(Application.kt:16)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'java.lang.Integer com.mongodb.ConnectionString.getThreadsAllowedToBlockForConnectionMultiplier()'
    at com.mongodb.MongoClientURI.getOptions(MongoClientURI.java:351)
    at com.mongodb.Mongo.createCluster(Mongo.java:724)
    at com.mongodb.Mongo.<init>(Mongo.java:312)
    at com.mongodb.Mongo.<init>(Mongo.java:308)
    at com.mongodb.MongoClient.<init>(MongoClient.java:326)
    at com.example.di.ModulesKt$appModules$1.invoke(modules.kt:17)
```

It seems the problem is in the MongoClient trying to connect to the cluster. Below is how I am trying to create the morphia datastore:

```
    val uri = MongoClientURI("mongodb+srv://admin:<password>@my-db-1dodp.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority")
    val client = MongoClient(uri)
    fun getDB(): Datastore { return Morphia().mapPackage("com.example.ktor").createDatastore(client, "db-name")}
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38633797/mongo-java-driver-2-14-0-change-deprecated-code